# FlowListView not working correctly with a simple example

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a basic FlowListView but I cant seem to get it working.  It works ok with a basic Xamarin ListView but when switched over to FLowListView it only shows the correct number of rows but they are empty.

Where am I going wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView" xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="rateStyle.ReviewPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <flv:FlowListView x:Name="listy" FlowColumnCount="2" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true">
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <!--
                        <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" />
                        -->
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
public partial class ReviewPage : ContentPage
{
    public ReviewPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var data = new List<Outfit>();
        var a = new Outfit { Title = "aaa", Picture="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8625/15806486058_7005d77438.jpg" };
        var b = new Outfit { Title = "bbb", Picture = "https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4011/4308181244_5ac3f8239b.jpg" };
        var c = new Outfit { Title = "ccc", Picture = "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7423/8729135907_79599de8d8.jpg" };

        data.Add(a); data.Add(b); data.Add(c);

        listy.ItemsSource = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working ? I'm facing similar problems

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't figured this bit out yet, you need to set FlowItemsSource, not ItemSource. Like this:

```
public partial class ReviewPage : ContentPage
{
    public ReviewPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var data = new List<Outfit>();
        var a = new Outfit { Title = "aaa", Picture="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8625/15806486058_7005d77438.jpg" };
        var b = new Outfit { Title = "bbb", Picture = "https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4011/4308181244_5ac3f8239b.jpg" };
        var c = new Outfit { Title = "ccc", Picture = "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7423/8729135907_79599de8d8.jpg" };

        data.Add(a); data.Add(b); data.Add(c);

        listy.FlowItemsSource = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to add a new item to the existing list?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale That's a matter of modifying the FlowItemsSource directly.  I'd use an ObservableCollection instead of a list in that case and then a simple data.Add() will work.

Otherwise, you'd have to still data.Add() your new item, then re-assign FlowItemsSource to the data collection.

Comment: am using MVVM pattern

Comment: @PrashantPimpale instead of new'ing up data like above, set listy.FlowItemsSource to your ObservableCollection in your ViewModel.  Then, any changes you make to the collection from your ViewModel will be reflected in the UI.